# SML datatype casting: binding not exhaustive

Tags: types, sml

I have this "shape" as *The Little MLer* calls it

```
datatype 'a pizza =
         Bottom
         | Topping of ('a * ('a pizza))
```

and this

```
datatype fish =
         Anchovy
         | Lox
         | Tuna
```

and here is an object of this datatype

```
Topping (Tuna, (Topping (Anchovy, Topping (Lox, Topping (Tuna, Bottom)))))
```

which is of type `fish pizza`. Now, when I try this

```
val Topping (f1,f2) = Topping (Tuna, (Topping (Anchovy, Topping (Lox, Topping (Tuna, Bottom)))))
```

This is the warning

```
stdIn:1.6-514.6 Warning: binding not exhaustive
:           Topping (f1,f2) = ...
: val f1 = Tuna : fish
: val f2 = Topping (Anchovy,Topping (Lox,Topping (Tuna,Bottom))) : fish pizza
```

What I need is a way to access the `Tuna` as `f1` while `f2` would be the

```
(Topping (Anchovy, Topping (Lox, Topping (Tuna, Bottom))))
```

like a list's head and tail. Why the warning? How can I get a `x::xs` sort of format for easy head-tail manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning because your pattern doesn't match `Bottom` - the matched value isn't evaluated at that time, only the type is known.

Since you know that the pizza isn't `Bottom`, you can safely ignore it.